# Confusing webpack syntax. Trying to fix a webpack.config file from an old tutorial from 2017

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am fairly new when it comes to modern web development paradigms.

I have recently read this article to get myself up to speed.
https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/modern-javascript-explained-for-dinosaurs-f695e9747b70

and am currently trying to implement the tutorial in this article
https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2

Both are from 2017 and there have been apparently large syntactical changes to webpack since then. I was wondering if someone could help explain why I get this error

```
PS C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact> npm run build:dev

> ASPNetCoreReact@1.0.0 build:dev C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact
> webpack --mode=development

C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\webpack.config.js:23
   { test: /\.css$/, use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader?
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:226:18)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:172:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:115:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:117:6)
    at C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:124:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:122:15)
    at yargs.parse (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:368:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sgibson\source\repos\ASPNetCoreReact\ASPNetCoreReact\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ASPNetCoreReact@1.0.0 build:dev: `webpack --mode=development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ASPNetCoreReact@1.0.0 build:dev script.
```

When utilizing this webpack.config.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./wwwroot/source/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: extractCSS.extract(["css-loader?minimize"]) },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Webpack syntax is very confusing to me. I don't really follow the flow that is happening here.

Comment: While I was editing your post I saw in my IDE the linter was throwing an error in the syntax because you had a new line break between the `css-loader?` and `minimize`. That's probably the unexpected token that Webpack couldn't resolve

Comment: interesting. I hadn't considered that and just assumed the syntax was out of date. I'll make sure to look for things like that in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. My apologies for not giving myself a little more time to dive deeper. I was just feeling really lost. I needed to read up on each individual component in the webpack file to figure out how they should be interacting/declared in 2019 versus in the versions they were in 2017.

This ended up clearing all of the errors out

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('allstyles.css');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
   optimization: {
      minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
   },
  entry: './wwwroot/source/app.js',
  output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
            filename: 'bundle.js'
          },
  plugins: [
   extractCSS,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
               $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
                     }),
          ],
   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: "style-loader",
              use: "css-loader"
            })
          },
         {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: {
               loader: 'babel-loader', options: {
                  presets:
                     ['@babel/preset-env']
               }
            }
         },
      ]
   }

};
```